# How do I snap to an interstection

Tags: snapping

I have two walls that meet in the corner, one is at an angle and the other is square. I would like to be able to drag the selected edge up to match the angled wall. I want it to align exactly because I'm using the model to figure out precise dimensions. What's the easiest way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any good way to snap to intersection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/805/is-there-any-good-way-to-snap-to-intersection)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/how-can-i-add-vertices-to-intersection-of-two-edges/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62840/how-to-make-a-vertex-meet-an-edge-exactly